# how to get page url without decode in javascript?

Tags: javascript, encoding, url-encoding, urldecode

How can I get page URL from `window.location.href` without decode in javascript?

For example we can not get exactly this URL: `http://example.com/report#title=example_report&url=project_chart%2F%3Fproject_id%3D77`.

When we use `window.location.href` in javascript , we will get this URL:

`http://example.com/report#title=example_report&url=project_chart/?project_id=77`.

But I want to get exactly the same real URL.

Any solution?

### Edited

as @Eugenio told, `$(document)[0].URL` works fine , but Is it safe?!

Comment: Browser decodes it for you. You can always url encode your string in JS. But why you need exactly the same URL?

Comment: real url? you mean http://example.com/? or http://example.com/report or what?

Comment: Pretty sure he means the url with all the % signs and values

Comment: @JoeWarner, i want `http://example.com/report#title=example_report&url=project_chart%2F%3Fproject_id%3D77`

Comment: Have you tried `document.url` ?

Comment: @Justinas , i need this for getting `#` part and converting it to JSON object, like `{url : 'project_chart%2F%3Fproject_id%3D77'}`

Comment: @Eugenio , tnx , `$(document)[0].URL` works fine , but how ? is it safe ?

Comment: @userx What do you mean by safe? Anyway, as far as I know the only difference between `document.url` and `window.location.href` is that the first gives you the url as a string, while the other return the url already formatted. I think you can even try `window.location.href.toString()`. Not sure about the last one though. Cheers!

Comment: @Eugenio, thank you so much, i mean does it work on all of browsers? also it seems works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make a clear and concise answer I will sum up all the comments.

For your problem the best solution is to use `document[x].url` where x is the index of the URL part that you want to use.

The main difference for your problem between `window.location.href` and `document.url` is that the last one gives you the URL in a string format, whilest the other return the URL already parsed.

Using either one is completely normal and safe and is [widely adopted in all modern browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/URL).

```js
var url1 = document.URL;
var url2 = window.location.href;

document.getElementById("documentUrl").append (url1);
document.getElementById("windowLocationUrl").append (url2);
```

```html
<div id="documentUrl">document.url: </div>
<div id="windowLocationUrl">window.location.href: </div>
```

There is no difference in this particular snippet example because there are no parameters attached to the URL. Anyway, hope this helped. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

Try to use `encodeURI`.

As for example;

```
var url = window.location.href;
var originalUrl = encodeURI(url);
```

This function(`encodeURI`) encodes special characters, 
except: , / ? : @ & = + $ #

You can use `encodeURIComponent()` to encode these characters.

Comment: looks like this encodes all of URL parts , but i need some of my URL.i try to send a URL as a GET parameter.

Comment: Ok, so just take the part of the url from full url string, and use the function `encodeURI`.

Comment: in a URL we are expecting for any thing. we can not detect which of parts is the url param if all of URL be in decode mode. whats your idea about `$(document)[0].URL` ?

Comment: Are you getting your expected part using `$(document)[0].URL`? And if you explain which part of url you want to actually encode, then I can give you some insights.

Comment: i need to convert `#` part to JSON obeject.

Comment: Ok, then split the url string via '#' character and take the second part to encode. To split use String.split() function in JS.

Comment: when i encode `title=example_report&url=project_chart%2F%3Fproject_id%3D77` , it will be `title%3Dexample_report%26url%3Dproject_chart%252F%253Fproject_id%253D77`., now how to detect keys and values ?!

Comment: Ok, so basically now you are arising another issue to get key and value, right? and this is out of the original question's scope. Right?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `encodeURIComponent`, but you have to get the part of a string you want to encode.

```
encodeURIComponent(window.location.href.split('&url=')[1])
```

Or you can use RegExp to be more precise.

Comment: in a URL we are expecting for any thing. we can not detect which of parts is the `url` param if all of URL be in decode mode.

Answer (score 1):

as @Eugenio told, 
i use below code and it works fine:

```
var url = $(document)[0].URL;
```